# Is there a way to compress mongodb query result for transfer on wire?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

My app is using MongoDB Template to query MongoDB. Some query result set is pretty large, 40-50MB. Is there a way to compress the result set for transfer and then when Java receives the result, decompress to get the full result?

Based on @Joe's suggestion, I add the compressor config in the URI.

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb+srv://userName:password@xxxxxxx.mongodb.net/test?compressors=zlib&retryWrites=true&w=majority
      database: mydb
```

No improvement to me. Did I miss anything thing?

Answer (score 3):

MongoDB 3.6 offers wire protocol compression which does exactly that.

https://emptysqua.re/blog/driver-features-for-mongodb-3-6/#wire-protocol-compression
https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/driver/tutorials/compression/

Comment: spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      uri: mongodb+srv://userName:password@abc.mongodb.net/test?compressors=zlib&retryWrites=true&w=majority
      database: mydb
I use the above to connect, but can't see any difference. Anything I missed? don't know how to format in comments. It is a yml config section

Comment: that looks like the way to force it to use zlib for wire compression.  Try capturing the packets to see if they are compressed.